# Build option in intellij will be grayed out when opened the project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am new to Intellij. When I open my project, it takes hell lot of time for my build options to be enabled. When I select debug option, in the background task build task will be running but with not any additional information. It will take good amount of time to complete. Any settings I need to change?

Comment: `for my build options to be enabled` what build options do you mean? Is it Build | 'Build Project' action? If you mean Run/Debug Configuration - it is not enabled until IDE has completed building the index for project. Nut it should happen only first time you open the project for the current major version.

Comment: yes @Andrey Build | Build Project is not enabled. Not only this, all the other options in Build tab will be grayed out. Only generate Ant build will be enabled.